# Get Play store views and installs like "Google Play Referral Flow" with google analytics reporting api

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I spent a few hours trying to get the "Play Store Views" and "Installs" metrics but I didn't found it how.

I checked the documentation where you could find all the [dimensions/metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) but those are not there.

I hope someone from the google analytics api could helps me with this issue.

[image: Google Play Referral Flow]

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981?hl=en might get you part of the way there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have searched high and low for this.  It would be very valuable information to have.    I was unable to find the information in the Google Analytics API or the Google play APIs.

I had to go as far as double checking with the Google Analytics dev team.

This information is not available through an API at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The data is available on the Developer Console.
On the ALL APPLICATIONS page, select your app and then User Acquisition (second item from top in left hand menu).